# std::is_assignable and abstract class

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++-concepts

Suppose you have an abstract class:

```
struct Abstr { virtual void f() = 0; };
static_assert(std::is_assignable<Abstr, Abstr>::value);
```

The assertion above fails with GCC (tested on version 10.3 and 11.2), but compiles just fine on Clang (tested on versions 12 and 13).

Also, with a custom implementation of the trait using concepts:

```
template <class T, class U>
concept is_assignable_concept = requires
{ std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>(); };
static_assert(is_assignable_concept<Abstr, Abstr>);
```

the assertion never fails with either compiler.

What is the correct behavior here?
Both are respected compilers, but I'm inclined to believe Clang is right here.

PD:
I wonder why not use concepts to implement traits. At least in this case, it turns out to be much shorter than the sfinae version and with apparently correct behavior.

Comment: Concepts were introduced in C++20, so that's why. Not everybody is using C++20...

Comment: _"I wonder why not use concepts to implement traits"_ because there are versions before C++20?

Comment: The concept you wrote is apparently the definition of `is_assignable`, so clang is at least inconsistent.

Comment: Note, there actually _is_ a concept in the std library: [`std::assignable_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/assignable_from).